# Add additional MS SQL Server to SharePoint Farm

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Dears,

Could you please advise how can I **add additional MS SQL Server to SharePoint Farm**
I tried to find any information in internet, but I didn't found any topics related with my problem

Regards,
Lure

Comment: What do you mean with "add additional MS SQL Server"? Do you need to use SQL Server Clustering or to add a new BCS connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cecilia, thank you for your comment. I found a solution.
Solution: we need to create a new content database with Database Server parameter.
After we just create a new site with this content database. That's all